# Once a user sorts a datagridview how do I get back the original row index?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, datagridview

say I display a datatable on a datagridview, then the user sorts it, and selects a row... I want to do something with the original datatable to the same row... but the row indexes in the datagridview and datatable are now out of sync.  How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things come to mind.

1. You can requery the DataTable's data source.
2. You can programmatically add a Column to your DataTable that acts as an index of the DT's original row order.  When you want to restore the sort order, sort on this column.  I've done this.  You can set the new Column's AutoIncrement property to true and the column's values will be filled in for you.

HTH

Comment: I can't see how I can requery the datatable's data source and still wind up with the row at position X from the datagridview. programmatically adding an index to the datatable as it comes in, may be viable, but seems like more overhead then should be needed for this simple operation.

Comment: You can programmatically set the selected row in the DGV after you requery.

Comment: How can adding an index as it comes in be "more overhead than needed"? You need an index. Assuming you can't modify the datatable, adding an index when you load it is "exactly as much overhead as needed".

Comment: I was hoping and expecting that the DataGridView had a sourceIndex property or something like that for this very type of situation. Now that I've learned [System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false)] this solution becomes far more useful.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the source for the data has an index, you can store the index as a hidden column in your datagridview.

Comment: and then traverse the entire table looking for that value?

Comment: Can you assign a unique key to each record in your datatable before you load it into your datagridview?  Then the index on the selected row would map to the index in your datatable.

Answer (score 0):

If your table has a primary key, get it from the selected row, then use the [DataTable.Select()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.select.aspx) method to locate that row in the datatable.

Comment: the data is now in a datagridview so I wouldn't be able to use datatable.select(),  can you tell me more about how this would work?

Comment: also no primary key is present on this datatable

Comment: DataTable.Select() would use expressions to locate rows that match the criteria in the expression. You do not need a primary key to do this (however datatable does not store the row index, so that is not returned, but the actual row is).  See the following page for an example.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50.aspx

Comment: dataTable.Select on a table with no primary key would seem to involve filtering by all the values, at that point I have the values and may as well just build an object or something?  If I had a column with a hidden index value, select doesn't let me remove that column to pass back just the row without the new index.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are trying to match the row indices of the your DataTable with the sort order indices of your DataGridView. In the example below, the sort column name is "index".

'Apply a sort order to the gridview
*table.DefaultView.Sort = "index ASC"*

'Assign the datasource of DataGridView to DataTable
*gridview.DataSource = table.DefaultView*

'Change the index value of the DataTable which will cause
' the DataGridView to resort the view. In this case, swap rows 0 and 1.
*table.Rows(0).Item("index") = 1*
*table.Rows(1).Item("index") = 0*

Now the order of the rows in **table** has not been changed, only the **gridview** sorts and displays the new order of the rows.

The only way I know of, although it is not a great solution, is as follows:

'Reassign the DataTable to its own sorted DefaultView
*table = table.DefaultView.ToTable()*

'Reapply a sort order to the gridview
*table.DefaultView.Sort = "index ASC"*

'Reassign the datasource of DataGridView to DataTable
*gridview.DataSource = table.DefaultView*

Now both the **table** and the **gridview** have the same row order.

Please post a better solution if you know of one. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was working my butt off to avoid using databinding on a datagridview. now that I've figured that stuff out this isn't really a problem.

I still feel the datagridview should automatically have a sourceindex property for each datarow, but with

- databinding
- a layer of business objects in between the db and the datagrid
- System.ComponentModel.Browsable(false) attribute

I can make the datagridviewRow hold a reference to the entire object itself, without it showing as a dataGridViewColumn

Answer (score 0):

Even as this question already has an answer, it is not good enough in my option.

I got the same problem and I solved it as explained below:

```vb
Dim row As DataGridViewRow = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0)
Dim obj as MyObject = CType(CType(row.DataBoundItem, DataRowView).Row, MyObject))

' Now I can get my original index using indexOf on my datasource
Dim originalIndex = MyDataSource.IndexOf(obj)
```

I can use `obj` to search for the desired index in another way to.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple actually:

```
For Each selectedRow As DataGridViewRow In yourGridView.SelectedRows

Dim originalIndex As Integer = dataTable.Rows.IndexOf(selectedRow.DataBoundItem.Row)

next

,where dataTable is the datasource of yourGridView
```

You can sort it as many time as you want and still get the original index which is defined in the source DataTable.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I wanted to update the database based on what the user had selected in the datagridview.  It worked good as long as the user did not sort the datagridview by clicking on one of the header columns.  To solve the problem I used the following:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewUsers.SelectedRows)
{
    //I could then access cells on each row to get the values
    string lastName = row.Cells["lastname"].Value;
    string userName = row.Cells["username"].Value;
    ...
}
```